# Problem with a code to draw a box around text

Tags: plain-tex

I want to enclose a text in a box. My problem is that when the code below is placed at the beginning of a line it causes a line-break/carriage-return (the box stays on a line by itself, the rest of paragraph starts at the next line). But it is OK when I use it in the middle or the end of a line. What is causing this behavior?

```
\def\boxit#1#2{\hbox{\vrule
\vtop{%
\vbox{\hrule\kern#1%
\hbox{\kern#1#2\kern#1}}%
\kern#1 \hrule}%
\vrule}}
\def\emptybox#1#2#3{\hbox spread #3{\hfil
\vtop spread #2{
\vbox spread #1{\vfil}
\vfil}}}
```

Comment: `\hbox` doesn't start horizontal mode; add `\leavevmode` as the first token in the replacement text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to what can be thought at first, `\hbox` doesn't start horizontal mode. The reason is that a `\vbox` can be made up by stacking `\hbox`es:

```
\vbox{\hbox{A}\hbox{B}\hbox{C}}
```

and this would result in

> A
>   B
>   C

and the width of the resulting `\vbox` would be that of the widest `\hbox`.

The same is true about `\vbox`, `\vtop`, `\box` and `\copy`. Conversely, `\unhbox` and `\unhcopy` applied to a box register containing an `\hbox` will start horizontal mode. If you intend to use those commands as starting paragraphs, add `\leavevmode`:

```
\def\boxit#1#2{\leavevmode
  \hbox{\vrule
    \vtop{
      \vbox{\hrule\kern#1%
        \hbox{\kern#1#2\kern#1}
      }%
      \kern#1 \hrule
    }%
  \vrule}%
}
\def\emptybox#1#2#3{\leavevmode
  \hbox spread #3{\hfil
    \vtop spread #2{
      \vbox spread #1{\vfil}
    \vfil}%
   }%
}
```

A more efficient macro for creating an empty box with specified height, depth and width is

```
\def\emptybox#1#2#3{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup\setbox0=\hbox{}%
  \ht0=#1%
  \dp0=#2%
  \wd0=#3%
  \box0
  \endgroup}
```